# how to give asp.net write permission to a folder in xampp server

Tags: asp.net, xampp

I want to upload a file .zip, .rar etc to server. I am saving these files to 'Files' folder in xampp server. But, how can i give write permission to asp.net so that it can save the selected file in the 'Files' folder.

```
 string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the identity (user) that the website's [application pool](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools) is using
   (in IIS manager).
2. Ensure that the user has write [access to the folder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).